# Pushing elements to an array in Jade

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to create an array in Jade and then loop through another and create a new array from it. I am doing something like:

```
         .metadata4
          - var prepopulate = []
          - if (entry.artist_ids)
            - for (var artist in entry.artist_ids)
              - var name = entry.artist_ids[artist]
              - prepopulate.push({id: name, name: name})
        input(type='text', class='token-input', data-url="/query", data-pre=prepopulate)
```

All this works awesome. However, it seems to add an extra element onto the end of the list (like its pushing the function push to the array or something). Anyone know why this may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this is happening and also didn't test it. as a workaround, what you can do is, declare a new `var i = 0;`
and then increment it inside the `for`. and put `prepopulate.push({id: name, name: name})` inside an `if` statement, like `if(i < entry.artist_ids.length - 1){...push...}`

Comment: I love it : `-var array = []` then `-array.push({time:"22h47"})` , thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this behavior, using the following data

```
entry = { "artist_ids": {1: "hello", 2:"robert"} }
```

I get the following data-pre:

```
[{"id":"hello","name":"hello"},{"id":"robert","name":"robert"}]
```

which is exactly what you wrote (although I suspect you wanted to replace id's name value with artist)

Maybe you could post your entry object?